# how to refresh my default Table model

Tags: java, swing

Hi This is my code[here i update my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hV8fS.jpg)
then i want to display the updated table. But every time i update the contents will get added to the previous list, i just want the new updated contents to be in the list. not the old one.[data getting updated to previous one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7oCu.jpg)

```
uptab=new JTable();
        uptab.setModel(model1);
        model1.setColumnIdentifiers(new Object[]{"No.","Item","cost"});
        sp2= new JScrollPane(uptab);
        sp2.setBounds(600,400,500,200);
        upd.add(sp2);


        int i = stmt.executeUpdate();  
        System.out.println(i +"records updated"); 

    //  model.fireTableDataChanged();

while(i!=0)
    {


        while(res1.next())
        {   
            String slno1=res1.getString("numb");
            String item3=res1.getString("itemname");
            String cost1=res1.getString("cost");
            model1.addRow( new Object[]{slno1,item3,cost1});    

        }
        i--;
    }
```

Comment: use `model.setRowCount(0);`. this deletes all rows. afterwards add the updated data

Comment: Please no pictures of code -- how can we copy, paste, compile and run an image. Instead try to get rid of the database code and post a viable [mcve] or [sscce](http://sscce.org) (please check out the links).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But every time i update the contents will get added to the previous list,

Before you start add data to the DefaultTableModel in your loop you can use:

```
model1.setRowCount( 0 );
```